# How to update MVC4 application to support Google authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-authentication

The old `OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();` in `(RegisterAuth())` is not working now as google has disabled this in April. I have done the registration on google developer, and I got my client id and secret id, but with mvc old template there is no place to use for them!  `RegisterGoogleClient()` doesn't accept a client id.

I checked the mvc5 OWIN classes, and there will be a lot to update if I go that way, because I already have lots of functionality built over identity and webmatrix classes.

If anyone can throw me a link or a suggestion, it will be great.